# How to test that Tomcat with APR and OpenSSL is caching SSL sessions?

Tags: tomcat, openssl, tomcat6, apr

We have an application running on Tomcat 6.0.32 and using JSSE (Java 1.6.0_26) for cryptographic communication (HTTPS). Recently, we've being testing with the APR connector and  OpenSSL.

How can we verify that the SSL sessions are being cached/reused or generated on every connection when using APR? Does APR writes SSL-related information to some log file?

When using JSSE we can see SSL handshake and session information in the tomcat log file (catalina.out) by passing `-Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl=ssl.handshake` to the JVM. These flags don't work when using APR though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command:

```
$ openssl s_client -reconnect -state -debug
```

shall give you some information as of OpenSSL session caching.

It would be nice if you could post the OpenSSL version your server is running. Concerning session caching, [there are well known vulnerabilities in some releases](http://openssl.org/news/secadv_20101116.txt).

Regards.

Comment: This approach was abandoned, so I never got to a solution. I'm Accepting the answer since it's the only one provided.